# Use ADODB to INSERT INTO specific table in an Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to use ADODB to execute a SQL INSERT INTO command into an Excel worksheet. I was able to insert into the worksheet when there was only one column in the worksheet using this code:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection

Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
Source=PathToFile.xls;Extended 
Properties=Excel 8.0;"

Connection.Open

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] VALUES('Test')"
Call Connection.Execute(SQL, , CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText Or ExecuteOptionEnum.adExecuteNoRecords)
```

But I want to have three separate tables in the same worksheet and specify which of the tables to insert into. How can I do this? I tried creating the tables, naming them, and using this SQL statement to specify a table but I kept getting the error: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'TestTable1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable1(ID) VALUES('test')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub TestInsert()

    InsertRecords Sheet4.Range("B3").CurrentRegion, _
               "insert into @ values('AAA','BBB','CCC')"

    InsertRecords Sheet4.Range("F3").CurrentRegion, _
               "insert into @ values('ZZZ')"

    InsertRecords Sheet4.Range("H3").CurrentRegion, _
               "insert into @ values('Whirled',99999)"

End Sub



Sub InsertRecords(rng As Range, sSQL As String)

    Const S_TEMP_TABLENAME As String = "SQLtempTable"
    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim sPath

       'name the selected range
       On Error Resume Next
       ThisWorkbook.Names.Item(S_TEMP_TABLENAME).Delete
       If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear

       On Error GoTo haveError
       ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=S_TEMP_TABLENAME, RefersToLocal:=rng

       sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

       oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                  "Data Source=" & sPath & _
                  ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""

       oConn.Execute Replace(sSQL, "@", S_TEMP_TABLENAME)

      Exit Sub

haveError:
      MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It took me a minute to catch the Hello Whirled but it made me laugh haha